# Loop error. Dnsmasq and Nginx

Tags: loops, nginx, server, dnsmasq

In my work I have a dnsmasq server and a Nginx Server and I try this:

If someone type MalwareSite.com(example) dnsmasq redirect to my nginx server and show a page with a warning and a button to redirect to MalwareSite.com.

But this is an error because is a loop, if a button is clicked, dnsmasq redirect again to nginx and...... loop.
this is my nginx page:

```
window.location.replace("MalwareSite.com");
```

and this is the line in dnsmasq to redirect to my nginx server

```
address=/MalwareSite.com/192.168.15.231
```

any idea to solve this or another workaround????

sorry for my english. Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

use resolver directive to specify an external DNS server, which will tell nginx proper internet address
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver